# VB.NET Webservice (asmx) - Return a PDF

Tags: c#, vb.net, asmx

I have an application that creates a PDF document based on user input. I now have to use this PDF and return this from a web service to serve a different application. Is there any way to do that from a web method. Because I am not able to return a File from web method all I can do is return a FileStream.

Thank you.

Comment: You can always turn the filestream into a base64-encoded string which the client can un-encode and write to a file on their side.

Comment: Has the PDF document been written to disk (you could use [Response.TransmitFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.transmitfile)) or is it in memory ([How to download memorystream to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558317/how-to-download-memorystream-to-a-file)

Comment: @AndrewMorton PDF file is first saved on to a directory and then I want to return that from a method in web service.